# Set contract storage directly at deployment

Tags: contract-deployment, storage, mapping

Is there a way to pre-define a contracts storage when deploying it?

Say I want a mapping to be filled with 1000 entries but want to avoid having to pay gas for adding every entry on its own.

Since storage is just a key-value map, I was wondering if can't just hardcode its initial state.

Answer (score 0):

A contract storage can be modified in two cases:

- At contract deployment
- A function is called during a transaction

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 1000 entries during deployment by modifying the constructor. But you will still have to pay for the gas consumed.